# Iterate over Django Model object to translate (translate 3.6.1) specific fields (all TextFields and all JSONFields)

Tags: python, django, django-models, iteration, machine-translation

How does one iterate over a Django Model object to translate all TextFields and all JSONFields before sending to template. Let me elaborate. I have a Django model `models.py` like the following:

```
SOME_TEXT_CHOICES = (
        ('choice_one', _('Choice One')),
        ('choice_two', _('Choice Two')),
        ('choice_three', _('Choice Three'))
    )


from django.db import models

class SomeModel(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    some_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    some_address = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    sometime = models.TimeField(default=datetime.time(15, 00))
    some_choices = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=SOME_TEXT_CHOICES, null=False, blank=False)
   some_text_one = models.TextField(max_length=1000, null=False, blank=False)
   some_text_two = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
   some_json_field = models.JSONField(help_text=_('JSON field: {"key_text1":"value_text1","key_text2":"value_text2"}'), null=True, blank=True)
```

And I have a `views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from translate import Translator
from .models import SomeModel


def detail_view(request, slug):
    context = {}

    context_somemodel = get_object_or_404(SomeModel, slug=slug)
    
    translator = Translator(from_lang='en', to_lang='es')
 
    # How to iterate through the context_somemodel to update all
    # TextField(s) and JSONField(s) with the translator.translate() method  
    # before sending to the template?

    context['somemodel'] = context_somemodel

    return render(request, 'templates/detail_template.html', context)
```

The original content of the model is in English and it should be translated into Spanish.

I tried to update/translate a single field with `SomeModel.objects.filter(slug=slug).update(some_text_one=translator.translate(F('some_text_one')))` but I get an error message: name 'F' is not defined.